# Как через Python определять запуск стрима на Twich

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, requests

Имеется программа, написанная на Python и использованием Selenium, Tkinter. В ней описана панель управления ботами для твича (они выполняют функццию просмотра трансляции, автоматической сборы баллов твич). Но эта программа полезна когда я её запускаю однновременно с активной траннсляцей стрима и я не всегда слежу за тем, начал ли стример трансляцию чтобы запустить программу. Как реализовать чтобы запущенная программа, автоматически определяла запустил ли стример трансляцию и если стример запустил её, то программа бы автоматически запускала нужные функции для фарма баллов? Нужна именно процедура проверки, чтобы я отошел, а программа сама детектит начало стрима.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

channelName = '39daph'

contents = requests.get('https://www.twitch.tv' + channelName).content.decode('utf-8')

if 'isLiveBroadcast' in contents: 
    print(channelName + ' is live')
else:
    print(channelName + ' is not live')
```